# В чем ошибка в коде? Ошибка времени выполнения: Входная строка имела неверный формат. Нужно ввести число с 3 цифрами в целой и 4 в дробной частях

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

```
var x, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11: integer;
begin
read(x);
x1 := trunc(x);
x2 := x1 div 100;
x3 := x1 div 10 mod 10;
x4 := x1 mod 10;
x5 := x2 + x3 + x4;
x6 := x - x1;
x7 := x6 div 1000;
x8 := x6 div 100 mod 10;
x9 := x6 div 10 mod 10;
x10 := x6 mod 10;
x11 := x7 + x8 + x9 + x10;
writeln(x5);
writeln(x11);
end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var
  x: double;
  x1, x2, ...
begin
  ...
  x6 := trunc((x - x1) * 10000);
  ...
```